# how to simplify this statement using indexOf?

Tags: javascript, arrays, instanceof, simplify

How can I simplfy the following text inside the if statement in Javascript using "indexof"?

```js
if (a === 1 || a === 2 || a === 3) {
  return "correct";
};
```

I am guessing an array needs to be made for 1,2, and 3, but am unsure of how to us instanceof after that

*edited to say indexOf instead of instanceOf

Comment: `instanceof` won't help you, but `.indexOf()` might.

Comment: Just a quick note, the semicolon after the if statement is unecessary.

Comment: whats wrong with: `a>=1 && a<=3` ?

Comment: @LukeP perhaps `a=1.2` should not evaluate true

Comment: @LukeP because then `a` can be non-integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) operator tests whether an object has in its prototype chain the prototype property of a constructor.

In your case, `instanceof` wont help you. You can use [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) with array as follow.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];

// Check if a is present in the arr array
if (arr.indexOf(a) > -1) {
    return "correct";
}
```